# Using StreamWriter to append text

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, file

The following program should open/create a file and write the current date to it's end every  time.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace roughDraft
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            StreamWriter oFile = File.AppendText("baza.txt");
            string output = "Current date and time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");


            oFile.WriteLine(output);

            Console.WriteLine(output);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why does it only create an empty file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should always put `StreamWriter` objects in a `using` statement so they get closed properly.

```
using (StreamWriter oFile = File.AppendText("baza.txt"))
{
    string output = "Current date and time: " 
                  + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
    oFile.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Alternatively, you can manually call the [`Close` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) on the `StreamWriter`, but the `using` statement, to me, is much easier and less error-prone.

Comment: Or use flush.  You did not answer the op though, as you did not explain why his solution does not work (the buffer does not get written to disk unless Flush or Close is called).

Comment: @FishBasketGordo , your example helped me a lot, but it's uncomplete- now it writes to the file, but only if it doesn't exist. There is no such problem when calling Close() method instead. You have also didn't explained the reason why my program didn't worked in the way I dreamt. Thanks trispeed for you comment, now I'm 100% satisfied :)

Comment: @kowalt: So `using` statement calls `dispose` which calls `flush(true,true)` whereas `StreamWriter.WriteLine` only writes to the file immediately when  [`AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx)`==true.`

Answer (score 1):

Its creating empty file because you are writing in it but not closing the StreamWriter

**like this oFile.Close();**